# Sgml returns some warnings

Tags: html, prolog, sgml

I use the sgml library of prolog to extract information about a web page. I use this instruction to extract all:

```
load_structure('file.html', List, [dialect(sgml), shorttag(false), max_errors(-1)])
```

the system loads the page but i have some warnings, for instance:

```
WARNING:SGML2PL(sgml): inserted omitted end-tag for "img"
WARNING:SGML2PL(sgml): inserted omitted end-tag for "br"
WARNING:SGML2PL(sgml): entity "amp" does not exist
```

How can i do to eliminate this warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this syntax

```
get_html_file(FileOrStream, P) :-
        dtd(html, DTD),
        load_structure(FileOrStream, [P],
                       [ dtd(DTD),
                         dialect(sgml),
                         shorttag(false),
                         syntax_errors(quiet),
                         max_errors(-1)
                       ]).
```

the option `syntax_errors(quiet)` should do.

I recall I had some hard time parsing old pages with errors.
Error handling can be complicated, some tool like [tags soup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/), being more tolerant, could help in getting the work sone...

Comment: In dtd(html,DTD), what are the values of variable DTD? I must insert it?

Comment: no, SWI-Prolog will fill the structure on the fly, while parsing. It's optional, kind of a recap... I sometime used to deepen the analysis.